# Cannot call Kotlin variable value which declared by function

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I am declaring a global variable called `basic_id` inside class.

```
class userOverview : AppCompatActivity() {
   private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
   private var basic_id : String = "00"

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.user_overview)
       database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

       loadBasicDetails() //this function will assign basic_id a non-zero value

       //Display Toast of current value of basic_id
       Toast.makeText(this, "On loading - "+basic_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

       button.setOnClickListener() {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Button clicked - "+basic_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }
   }

   private fun loadBasicDetails() {
        val q : Query =  database.getReference("basic").orderByChild("epf_no").equalTo("12345")
            q.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (dataChild in data.children) {
                        val basicDetails = dataChild.getValue(basicDetailsModel::class.java)
                        basic_id = basicDetails!!.basic_id
                    }
                }
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {error.toException()}
            })
    }
}
```

I am assigning database values to custom object (`basicDetailsModel::class.java`) and assign it's value to global variable `basic_id` (*Its works fine*) 
When activity starts, it shows a toast `"On loading - 00"` 
But when clicking button, it shows a toast `"Button clicked - 06"` 

Why its not working on Toast `"On loading - 06"`

Comment: add your class basicDetailsModel and firebase databasse structure with key

Comment: Place your first toast in loadBasicDetails function after you are done assigning value. First toast doesn't have the value of basic_id. Your second toast is on button click. By the time you click button the value is already there with basic_id.

Comment: That’s not a global variable. It’s defined inside a class so it’s a class member property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ValueEventListener doesn't run as soon as you've registered it, it will be triggered after the network request has been finished, you may wanted to use coroutines, but a simple and ideal solution for your case would be to use a callback here.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //...
    loadBasicDetails { // will be triggered after variable is set :)
        Toast.makeText(this, "On loading - "+basic_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }       
    //...
}

private inline fun loadBasicDetails(crossinline callback: () -> Unit) {
    database.getReference("basic").orderByChild("epf_no").equalTo("12345")
        .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {
                //... set the variable
                callback()
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {error.toException()}
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `"On loading -..."` `Toast` is shown `basic_id` variable does not have time to change, bcz you are making an asynchronous network request, which may execute some time depending on internet connection. So `Toast` `"On loading -..."` will be shown before `basic_id` variable is changed.